# How to integrate Xcode IB into NativeScript?

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript

I'm trying to integrate native UI from Xcode storyboard to NativeScript but I have no clues at this time.

I have taken a look at this [discussion](https://github.com/NativeScript/ios-runtime/issues/219)  and [example app](https://github.com/NativeScript/ios-runtime/tree/master/examples/Gameraww) (which I have cloned but cannot run it). The idea is to expose the Xcode IB to NS and let the controller written in TypeScript.

If anyone has approached this please give me some instruction. Any help would be appreciated also.

Comment: Storyboards are not officially supported in nativeScript as of this momnet (the issue itslef is marked as feature)

Comment: @NickIliev how about XIB file? I might not really need storyboard